# How to display an image full size with ImageView?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have problem when I try to display the image with full size.
I tried to display image with wrap_content. But it is smaller real image.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/screen1_logo" />
```

[image]

I go to the properties of this image and see some information: dimentions 211 x 74. Then I try to display image with fixed width and height. I see it's bigger.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="211px"
        android:layout_height="74px"
        android:src="@drawable/screen1_logo" />
```

[image: ImageView with wrap_content]
is it right way? do we must to fix size to display image with full size?
Please help me to explain and resolve this problem.

Answer (score 11):

add a `scaleType` to your ImageView

```
 <ImageView
     android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/screen1_logo" />
```

from the doc `android:scaleType="center"`

> Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.

Comment: I tried android:scaleType with all avaiable values. but image was displayed the same

Comment: where did you put the bitmap ? Did you put it inside one of the res/drawable folder ?

Comment: I put it into drawable-hdpi folder

Comment: have your mobile a screen with density hdpi?

Comment: my density is 320dpi. so it is xhdpi
I try to put image into drawable folder. the image is displayed with full size :)

Comment: yes, but I'm not clear about it. if I put image into hdpi, xhdpi folder, image will be smaller. if I put image into mdpi, image will be displayed as well

Comment: res/drawable probably do not perform the scaling process on the bitmap when it is loaded. You should read the screen support guide, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding in xml file (ImageView properties) android:adjustViewBounds="true".

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photoViewer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a scaleType attribute to your view:

```
android:scaleType=""
```

The available options can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: If you look on the link the available options are explained. It sounds like you want android:scaleType="centerInside"

Comment: :( I also try it.but the image's still smaller real image

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying that you want the image to be larger than it is?

Comment: You can change android:layout_width="match_parent" and "android:layout_height="match_parent" to make the imageView bigger?

Answer (score 1):

Please Define scale type as fitXY

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yourImageViewId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for scaleType

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I don't think so. Because I tried to set scaleType with all avaiable values

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

It's important don't to have width/height = wrap_content because in that way your imageView
size is equal to photos so it can't be moved.

Here you can see what is going to look like.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView