# android xml keep image size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying tot display 3 images:
- play button on the center
- two icons on the right

it's like: [___x__xx]

I added two black images on the left so that the playbutton while centered.
The problem now is that the two icons are not the original sizes, but fetched.
How can i solve this?

my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutText1"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spacex"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spacex"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnPlayPause"
        android:background="@drawable/togglebutton_playpause"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textOff=" "
        android:textOn=" "
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/netwerkImg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/netwerkImg"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:id="@+id/exitImg"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you should be able to find the answer here: [How to display an image full size with ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564753/how-to-display-an-image-full-size-with-imageview)

However, since there are many different device sizes, I would advise against that.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the  android:layout_width and android:layout_height to a value, when you set wrap_content be sure that your images will not appear in the same way using different devices, the design will be deformed.
for example :

```
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
```

Also to modify :

```
    android:scaleType="centerInside" to   android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Also add :

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: the two icons disappeared from the screen

Answer (score 0):

Use scaletype attribute of imageview.

```
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```